# How to loop through a code in Codeigniter for every user?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have code that calculates the total working hours of a employee.
I provide the login entries array and logout array. So That code calculates the total hours, seconds and min an employee has worked.

This is the code:

```
<?php
                $loginarry = $attendances;
                $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
                $timeduration=0;
                $login_i=0;
                $logout_i=0;


                echo '<table border="1px"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
                echo '<tr><th>Login</th><th>Logout</th><th>Duration</th></tr>';

                //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
        while(true)
        { 
            if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
                break;

            if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
            {
                //echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");


echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." </td><td>Not Available</td><td>Not Available</td></tr>");


    //          echo ("<tr> <td>".$loginarry->date_data." </td><td> Data Not Available</td></tr>");
                $login_i++;
                continue;
            }

            if(($login_i+1) == count($loginarry) && ($logout_i+1) < count($logoutarry))
            {
                echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
            $logout_i++;
            continue;
            }

            if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
            {
                echo ("<tr><td> Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<td>Data Not Available</td></td></tr>");
                            $logout_i++;
                continue;
            }
            //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

            //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
            if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
            //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
            {
                echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td><td>Data Not Available</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
                $login_i++;
                continue;
            }

           //
            if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
            //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
                    {
                echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");

                            $logout_i++;
                            continue;
                    }

            //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
            if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
            {
                echo(" <tr><td> Data Not Available</td> <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td> <td>Data Not Available</td> </tr>");
                            $logout_i++;
                            continue;
            }

            echo ("<tr><td> ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td>  <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."</td>");




            $singleduration = ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
            if($singleduration > 43200)//12 hours X 3600 seconds)
            {   
                 //$timeduration += $singleduration;
                 echo ("<td class='danger'>Huge duration - not considered - please contact HR (".$singleduration.")</td></tr>");
            }
            else
            {
                 $timeduration += $singleduration;
                 echo ("<td>".gmdate("H:i:s",$singleduration)."</td></tr>");
            }
            $login_i++;
            $logout_i++;

        }

            echo ("</table>");

            //$finaltime=gmdate("H:i:s",$timeduration);
            //$timedurationstr = ConvertSecondsToStr($timeduration);
            $hours = 0;
            if($timeduration > 3600)
            {
                $hours = floor($timeduration/3600);
                $timeduration -= (3600*$hours);
            }
            $min = 0;
            if($timeduration > 60)
            {
                $min = floor($timeduration/60);
                $timeduration -= (60*$min);
            }
            $seconds = $timeduration;



           //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total Hours Worked ". $finaltime." Hours</center></h3></div></div>");
           echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $hours." Hour(s) ".$min." Minute(s) ".$seconds." Second(s)</center></h3></div></div>");
           //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $timedurationstr." </center></h3></div></div>");

                ?>
```

So at last it returns the hours an employee has worked. This code is in my view.

Now I want to calculate those values for every user in my database.
I don't know how to loop though all users and run this code so i can get every user's total working time.

**In Controller** i fetch users and login and logout entries like this.

```
$users = $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();


    $loginarry = $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->all_login();
    $logoutarry =$this->data['attendances_logouts'] =$this->attendance_m->all_logout();

        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);
```

Now how to show each user's total working hours ?

**This is my code to fetch the login and logout entries**

```
ublic function all_login($emp_id = NULL)
{



        $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");

        $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");

        $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');

        $this->db->select('*');

        $this->db->from('daily_data2');


        $this->db->where('entry >','100');

        $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");  

        $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");



        $query = $this->db->get();

        $res   = $query->result();        

        return $res;

}




public function all_logout()
{


          $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");


          $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");



          $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');

          $this->db->select('*');

          $this->db->from('daily_data2');



          $this->db->where('entry <','100');
          $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");  

          $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");



          $query = $this->db->get();



           $res   = $query->result();        

          return $res;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is how you calculated all the time, maybe you should make a function with attendance as a parameter. And then you can get list of user as attendance and looping it

```
public function calculatedTime(attendance){

//Your coding here

}
```

and You can looping it to get the time

```
foreach($loginarry as $att){

     $this->calculatedTime($att);

}
```

Try to make coding as simple as possible, if need to repeat it, just make a function and call it.

Comment: Where should be my function? in controller?

Comment: i give the array to my view then there its all calculated. So what should be my flow now

Comment: yes, it should be on controller. And just pass the array on View. So at View, you only call the data.

Comment: can u please write a sample code for the same using my code in question

Comment: how will the function TimePerUser and Get all user talk with each other? i mean the users function fetches all the users and time gets the time but how to specify each users' time

Comment: I add $data[$key], that mean, in the array user Index, I am create new data time, try to print_r($data) it should be have the time variable in every data user

Comment: what is time here?? $data[$key]['time']=$this-